# Show that $ 4\times4$ matrix has real eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a real $ 4\times4$ matrix of the form
$$
C = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
c_{31} & c_{32} & 0 & c_{34} \\
c_{41} & c_{42} & c_{43} & c_{44}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The coefficients satisfy 
\begin{align*}
c_{31}, c_{32}, c_{41} &\ge 0,\\
c_{42} &> 0,\\ 
c_{34}, c_{43}, c_{44} &\le 0,
\end{align*}
and $\det(C) = c_{31} c_{42} - c_{32} c_{41} > 0.$

I want to show that the matrix has four distinct, real eigenvalues.
My approaches so far:

- Calculate the characteristic polynomial and use Mathematica to find the roots. The resulting formulas are too large to work with.
- Show that the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots) of the characteristic polynomial is positive. This works a little better, but again, the formulas are huge and ugly.

I would like to exploit the block structure of $A$, but I do not know how.

*Edit:* The coefficients I am actually working with are
\begin{align*}
 &c_{31} = \frac{\rho(\rho p_0 + 2 \lambda_0)}{p_0}, ~~~~~
 c_{32} = \frac{\rho \lambda}{p_0}, ~~~~~
 c_{34} = - \frac{\lambda}{p_0},\\
 &c_{41} = \frac{\rho \lambda_0}{p}, ~~~~~
 c_{42} = \frac{\rho (\rho p + \lambda \frac{n+1}{n})}{p}, ~~~~~
 c_{43} = - \frac{\lambda_0}{p}, ~~~~~
 c_{44} = - \frac{\lambda \frac{n-1}{n}}{p}
\end{align*}
with $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus\{0\}, ~~~\rho, p, p_0 > 0, ~~~\lambda, \lambda_0 \ge 0$ and $\max\{\lambda, \lambda_0\} > 0.$

Actually, one of the eigenvalues is $-\rho,$ so there are only three remaining (and none of these three is equal to $-\rho$). 
The three remaining eigenvalues are then the roots of a cubic equation. (This implies that at least one other root is real). The discriminant of the cubic equation, however, is still very complicated.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices for $\det(C-z)$, perhaps?

Comment: The eigenvalues are not necessarily distinct. For example, take $c_{31}=c_{42}=1$ and set all other entries to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I added the actual coefficients that I am working with.

Comment: It may be useful that the blocks in your matrix are all symmetric, so the eigenvalues of any block are real.  Then again, I can't immediately see where to go with that information.

Comment: Oh, sorry, are the $\lambda$ and $\lambda_0$ distinct quantities, or was that a typo?

Comment: No typo, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

**First attempt:**

$C$ has the block structure
$$
C = \pmatrix{0&I\\A&B}
$$
In particular, following the discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), we note that since the top two block commute, we have
$$
\det(C - \lambda I) = 
\det \pmatrix{-\lambda I&I\\A&(B - \lambda I)} = \\
\det[(-\lambda I)(B - \lambda I) - (I)(A)]=\\
\det[\lambda^2 I - \lambda B - A]
$$

---

**Second attempt:** Perhaps we can do a bit better with [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).  In particular,
$$
\operatorname{trace}(C) = c_{44}\\
\operatorname{trace}(C^2) = 
\operatorname{trace}\pmatrix{A&B\\AB&A+B^2} = 
2(c_{31}+c_{42} + c_{34}c_{43}) + c_{44}^2
$$
Note that $\operatorname{trace}(C^n) = \sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i^n$.

Comment: Isn't Sylvester's theorem about determinant of a blocks matrix true whenever all the blocks matrices commute with each other? I checked this possibility but the lower left 2x2 matrix doesn't necessarily commute with the right lower one.

Comment: @Joanpemo you only need two of them to commute

Comment: Thank you @Omnomnomnom . Do you have some reference to this result, please?

Comment: @Joanpemo see the link in my answer